# Will auto start service also launch the Application?

Tags: android, service

In my App, I have a remote service will auto start once receive  "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" broadcast. In this App I also have a class which extend "Application" class as the App entry point.

My question is when the service is launched by the Andriod OS when the device finish reboot, will the method "onCreate()" in the Application class get called first??

What if the service is local, will it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the onCreate() method WILL be called for the application to start. Since it is the natural flow of the activity life cycle.